# git shell command doesn't work with IdeaVim

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

I'm using intelliJ for IDE and installed `IdeaVim`. I'm trying to execute `git status` inside `vim` but it didn't work and nothing to show.

`:! git --help` and `:! ls -al` work

`:! cd /` doesn't work and showing the following error message.

```
Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory.
```

Can I use git command on shell inside vim? Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you simply want the information, you can open the Version Control or Terminal windows in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

From the IdeaVim reference manual:

```
==============================================================================
5. EX commands                                  *ex-cmd-index*

This is a brief but complete listing of all the ":" commands, without
mentioning any arguments.  The optional part of the command name is inside [].
The commands are sorted on the non-optional part of their name.

tag           command         action ~
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|:display|      :di[splay]      display registers
|:registers|    :reg[isters]    display the contents of registers
|:substitute| :s[ubstitute] find and replace text
```

The "brief but complete" suggests that these are the only three supported Ex-mode commands in IdeaVim.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked four years ago, but it still seems somewhat relevant

I am using IdeaVim with PyCharm 2021.2, and was having similar problems
because the shell you get by default with !! is a dos cmd shell.

So instead of cd try dir.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone down the road of editing the macros file by hand to create a macro that then opens the shell, and types out some text.

On my machine (mac) the macros are stored at:

/Users/my-user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/RubyMine2023.2/options/macros.xml

You can then edit them directly and set it to a keybinding. For example I have this macro:

```
<application>
  <component name="ActionMacroManager">
    <macro name="rfv">
      <action id="CopyAbsolutePath" />
      <action id="ActivateTerminalToolWindow" />
      <typing text-keycode="82:0;70:0;86:0;32:0">rfv&amp;#x20;</typing>
      <shortuct text="meta V" />
      <shortuct text="ENTER" />
    </macro>
  </component>
</application>
```

Which copies the file path from the editor, activates the terminal, types `rfv`  which is the name of my shell script, pastes the file path, and then hits enter. I've also mapped this macro `Macro.rfv` with a vim remapping.

It's a bit slow and janky but it's working for now.